# Why my seaborn.kdeplot was truncate

Tags: python, seaborn

[image enclosd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKXMc.png)

How can I make all data show? Now the child plot was cut

Here is my code:

```
# since it is a column and not index we need to set axis to 1

titanic_df['Personstatus'] = 
titanic_df[['Age','Sex']].apply(male_female_child,axis=1)
fig = sns.FacetGrid(titanic_df, hue='Personstatus', aspect=4)
fig.map(sns.kdeplot, 'Age', shade=True)

oldest = titanic_df['Age'].max()

fig.set(xlim=(0, 80))

fig.add_legend()
```

Comment: I think that is because of Seaborn setting the limits according to  the last mapping. You can easily set the y limits yourself, just as you did with the xlims, `.set(ylim=(0, 0.5))` or so.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the maximum axes limits are not being updated correctly is that `sns.kdeplot` calls `set_ylim`, which [turns off axes autoscaling by default](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L2857-L2859). So the axes would be scaled to the first data set that was plotted with `sns.kdeplot`, but then remain at that level for all following plots into the same axes.

This has been fixed since Seaborn 0.8.1, more info [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/commit/cd3540d81d674d751af8e47fd7a64076ff152de7) and [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/1308).